# What is the best convention for splitting up screens in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Let's say I want to split my `screens/LoginScreen.js` into separate components for readability (not necessarily reuse) - how should I approach this?

1. Do I create components inside the screens folder?

```
// EG
screens/LoginScreen.js
screens/LoginScreenComponentA.js
screens/LoginScreenComponentB.js
```

2. Or should I place them inside `/components` eg:

```
// EG
screens/LoginScreen.js
components/LoginScreen/LoginScreenComponentA.js
components/LoginScreen/LoginScreenComponentB.js
```

3. Or is there another convention? What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution with a `LoginScreen` folder inside the `components` directory looks fine. You can structure the screens and components in whatever the way that you find logical and easy to navigate and comprehend.

Personally speaking, I will reserve `components` directory for reusable components, each direct child directory of the `components` directory should be a component itself. If you have a child component that is combined of multiple components, all of these can live inside that component. Same thing applied to screens.

A proposed directory structure can be:

```
components
  - component-A
      - index.js // for re-export
      - ComponentA.js
      - ComponentATop.js
      - ComponentABottom.js
screens
   - screen-A
     - index.js
     - ScreenA.js
     - ScreenAPart1.js
     - ScreenAPart2.js
```

I find this structure easy to navigate and understand for a couple of reasons:

- An import from `src/components/component-a` will always give you ComponentA. If you need to find its related child components, they are always in the same directory. Same thing applied with screens.
- Only reusable components will be inside `components` folder. Components only used for a single screen will live inside the screen directory. You don't have to wonder where a component comes from.

Comment: Great advice. That makes the most sense to me, thanks heaps!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to go with the name of the sections you have in your login screen let say

make your folder structure like

```
Login/index.js 
Login/Components/LogoComponent.js
Login/Components/LoginInput.js
Login/Components/LoginButton.js
```

and if you wanted to reuse this input and button component then you can make folder structure like

```
src/Component/LogoComponent.js
src/Component/InputComponent.js
src/Component/ButtonComponent.js
```

// for screens like this

```
src/Screens/LoginPage.js
src/Screens/SignupPage.js
src/Screens/HomePage.js
```

for utilitis like alert or loader

```
src/Util/Loader.js
src/Util/Alert.js
```

for data hanlder like redux

```
src/Redux/Actions
src/Redux/Reducer
...
```

like this you can add separate folder for your use refer image for same
[image]